# checkboxgroup does not appear to the panel

Tags: java, swing, checkbox, jpanel

What I'm doing wrong ? I'm trying to add a checkboxgroup to the jpanel1. But I really can't understand why doesn't work ?
p.s. GUI is made by NetBeans matisse, then I manually edit code inside a new class.
Thanks

```
CheckboxGroup cbGroup = new CheckboxGroup();
  Checkbox importBox = new Checkbox("aaa", cbGroup, true);
  Checkbox specialBox = new Checkbox("bbb", cbGroup, false);


@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
private void initComponents() {

    jPanel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel1Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel1);

    jPanel1.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    jPanel1.add(importBox);
    jPanel1.add(specialBox);

    jPanel1Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGap(0, 210, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );
    jPanel1Layout.setVerticalGroup(
        jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGap(0, 100, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );
```

Comment: Where do you actually add jPanel1 to a JFrame? And is there a reason you're mixing awt and Swing instead of just using JCheckBoxes?

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  Don't mix Swing with AWT without good reason.  Here you would use `JCheckBox` and [`ButtonGroup`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/ButtonGroup.html).

Comment: @AndrewThompson MCVE??? Did the SSCCE get into trouble with the law or something?

Comment: @splungebob  The initial impetus was my request it be removed as a close vote.  Then it came to [this thread](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/214955/155831) & I felt I might be able to address some deficiencies in it (e.g. making both the letters and document shorter) and criticisms (read the thread) that it had attracted.  Moving it to SE also made me and a bunch of people more comfortable about linking to it.  I'm very happy with the result.

Answer (score 2):

You add the JCheckBox(s) to a container; perhaps like this

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            JFrame frame = new JFrame();
            ButtonGroup bg = new ButtonGroup();
            JCheckBox importBox = new JCheckBox("aaa", true);
            JCheckBox specialBox = new JCheckBox("bbb", false);
            bg.add(importBox);
            bg.add(specialBox);
            JPanel panel = new JPanel();
            panel.add(importBox);
            panel.add(specialBox);
            frame.add(panel);
            frame.pack();
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}
```

Which looks like this

[image: Using JCheckBox(s)]

Comment: [Initial Threads](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html)